# SLF4J: Failed to load class

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, slf4j

when i Run the Project then i see this error first and then the output also shown in the console window. I can't understand why this shown error 1st. I also pasted the error and output below

```
import java.util.Date;
import ConnectionDB.ConnectionDBClass;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
public class SimpleTriggerExample 
{
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    job.setName("dummyJobName");
    job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);

    //configure the scheduler time
    SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
    trigger.setName("dummyTriggerName");
    trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
    trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
    trigger.setRepeatInterval(5000);

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

}
}
```

2nd CLass name Hello.class

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloJob implements Job
{
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
throws JobExecutionException {

    System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");    

}

}
```

Error and output below (1st three lines error and next three lines are output)

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hello Quartz!
Hello Quartz!
Hello Quartz!
```

Comment: Have you read the URL provided by the error message?

Comment: where is the URL provided ?

Comment: In the error message! It is explicitly written: "See [http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) for further details".

Answer (score 4):

slf4j is not a logger but a logging facade. You'll have to add a logger (binding) to your classpath, if you want to do logging. If no logger is found, the slf4j API defaults to the built-in NOP logger.

If you do not want to log, simply ignore the warning.

Comment: I want logging but what should i do? guide me pls

Comment: Choose your favorite logger (logback, log4j, ...) and add the lib to your classpath. slf4j should discover the binding and use the logger. The idea is that we can use the slf4j API and replace the real logger at any time (or use any logger that is already present in the environment which is very useful for lib developers)

Answer (score 3):

slf4j is a facade it needs implementation binding to perform logging

If you see the link in the error message it says,

> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.
>
> since 1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.

Comment: but I also include the SLF jar file but still this error remain

Comment: name of jar is slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

Comment: add [`slf4j-log4j12.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar) to classpath or choose any of your favorite  logging framework slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar and add it to classpath